# Stress of word 'flagrant' /ˈfleɪɡrənt/ is Flagrant or FLAgrant or something else?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, dictionaries, word-stress

Stress of word 'flagrant' `/ˈfleɪɡrənt/` is `Flagrant` or `FLAGrant` or something else?

My problem is I don't know stress at `f` (Flagrant) or `fleɪ` (FLAgrant) (separation of sounds, because as you seen, it is coninuous IPA characters without separators).

Link https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flagrant?q=flagrant

The question is not specific to a word, I want ask about rule of stress in common. I am sorry because the question is basic in your side, but with me, it is new.

Please help me detect stress (please write in UPPERCASE) in few sample cases of:

`grammar` `/ˈɡræmə(r)/`  --> Is `Grammar` or `GRAMmar`?

`glamour` `/ˈɡlæmə(r)/` --> Is `Glamour` or `GLAMor`?

`association` `/əˌsəʊsiˈeɪʃn/` --> Is `associAtion`?

Comment: Why do you think that consonants might receive stress?

Comment: You just can't stress a consonant… it would make you spit a bit, like Joey Tribbiani & Gary Oldman's acting;)) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ISJS4gSBh0

Comment: Stress in English falls on syllables, not individual consonants.  All syllables must have a vowel.  I've found a nice lesson for you by Oxford Online English [here on youtube](https://youtu.be/Vu6UVwkUgzc?si=FNvzfCCRhHRcJnv0).

Answer (score 3):

Stress is based on syllables. A syllable is stressed. In particular, the nucleus of the syllable, the vowel, is stressed.

So /ˈfleɪ.ɡrənt/ (with a syllable division before /g/ means that the first syllable receives the stress.  "FLAgrant".

This then links to an equally important concept: rhyme.  The rhyme begins at the nucleus of the stressed syllable, and continues to the end of the word, so the rhyme is /-eɪ.ɡrənt/ and so flagrant rhymes with vagrant.